# Struct with generic argument appearing in trait bound only

Tags: rust

I'm trying to define a structure storing values of type `FnMut(&E)` for some generic type `E`:

```
struct Publisher<E,F> where F: FnMut(&E) {
    subscribers: Vec<F>
}
```

However, the Rust compiler then complains that `E` is never used, while omitting it causes it to fail since `E` is unknown. While it is possible to get around this using phantom data

```
struct Publisher<E,F> where F: FnMut(&E) {
    subscribers: Vec<F>,
    event: core::marker::PhantomData<E>
}
```

this approach doesn't seem very elegant. What would be the right way to address this issue?

Comment: Future versions of Rust might address this, but for now, embrace the phantom and stay spooky. 

Comment: Is there an RFC for this?

Comment: @HenningKoehler Closest I've been able to find is [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23246) on the issue tracker, where it was suggested that someone start an RFC, but no actual link to one is provided.

Comment: I've gone down this rabbit hole before, too, but ended up just using `PhantomData` and calling it done. Not sure there's an RFC per-se, but it seems low on the priority list since it "works" even if it's weird. If you can, kick that `FnMut` requirement to a function instead of pinning it to the top-level `Publisher`, that might help, but it's situational.

Comment: My specific problem was like `struct E<X>(Vec<Y<X>>)` didn't consider `X` to be "used" as it was too deeply embedded, so alas my code is haunted.

Comment: I think in my case the best approach is to omit the trait bound from `Publisher` entirely, and only apply it to functions that make use of `E` (as suggested in the discussion linked to by Silvio).